# Instant Rails 2.0 does not update gems and showing HTTP response 302 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, rubygems, response

I installed Instant Rails 2.0 on my windows 7 machine.
It has below versions :
Rails 2.0.2
gem 1.0.1
ruby 1.8.6

I am trying to update gem using command >gem update 
It shows message as below :

```
Updating installed gems...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteSourceException)
    HTTP Response 302 fetching http://gems.rubyforge.org/yaml
```

for all update operations, error is the same. Can somebody suggest how to update instant rails installed versions to latest or desired?

Manually updating will also do (just inform where to put the files and which directory to replace).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that instant rails is pretty much depricated. Rubyforge has pretty much gone away, and is replaced by rubygems.org. To get running on windows, check this out: http://railsinstaller.org/